# Coding standard for calling multiple methods on same object in Java/ C#

Tags: c#, java, coding-style

Could this code snippet

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.Append("Have a ");
builder.Append("nice day!");
```

be better written like this?

```
  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
  builder.Append("Have a ")
         .Append("nice day!");
```

In C# and Java, what would a better way to write it be?

Comment: Internally all boils down to same thing in memory. But redability wise, i would go for 1st approach.

Comment: There is no "better". The APIs are just somewhat different; the second option would be good *if you can provide it consistently* across all of `StringBuilder`'s API (otherwise it just seems arbitrary if only some methods allow chaining).

Comment: I usually prefer a style which my IDE supports to auto styling. So 1st is better.

Comment: Coding style questions are inherently subjective, I'm afraid. Subjective questions are not what SO is for, see [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for details.

Comment: I like the first approach, it's easier to debug IMO.

Comment: Personal taste... I prefer the 1st way.

Comment: I prefer `String s = new StringBuilder().append("Have a").append("nice day!").toString()` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern in the 2nd example is a "fluent API" / "fluent interface"; frankly neither is strictly *better* - but if the second exists it can be slightly inefficient not to use it. In .NET IL terms, the first syntax involves an extra `ldloc` and `pop` per iteration, which the second avoids - but that is rarely hugely significant. Either will work fine.

Personally, I would optimize for readability and convenience unless you know it is in a performance-critical spot.

Indeed, you could just use:

```
string s = "Have a " + "nice day!";
```

which the compiler (in C#, at least - I don't know about java) will compute at compile-time (since they are both constants) and compile down to a single `ldstr` (which is automatically interned, too).

Comment: Using `+` instead of StringBuilder's `append()` method creates a new String object on the heap (at least for variable Strings), which we want to avoid if using StringBuilder.

Comment: @alan.sambol that depends on usage; for example, in C#, the statement: `string s = name + ": " + count + " - " + comment;` is actually a single call to `string.Concat`, so only results in 1 additional `string` instance - the one we want. You can't do any better than that. If we were concatenating in a loop, then yes: `StringBuilder` would be ideal. The question does not show that, though.

Comment: That code snippet will work in Java.

Comment: @alan.sambol string concatenation in Java compiles to new StringBuilder and append sequence.